# How to fetch forecast API and return value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using OpenWeatherMap API to get JSON for forecast in my city.

I want to display mimimum temperature from 03:00 AM in next 3 days.
How can I do this?
This is what I have tried:

```
var temp1 = document.querySelector(".temp");
var image = document.querySelector(".weather-icon");
var minimum = document.querySelector(".temp_min");
var maximum = document.querySelector(".temp_max");

fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Belgrade,rs&appid=b44c47165b17c02b98173f5270d92e80')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

    var temp2 = Math.floor(data["main"]["temp"] - 273);
    var info = data["weather"][0]["main"];
    var press = data["main"]["pressure"];
    var hum = data["main"]["humidity"];
    var ltemp = Math.floor(data["main"]["temp_min"] - 273);
    var htemp = Math.floor(data["main"]["temp_max"] - 273);
    var k=0;
    var wind = data["wind"]["speed"];
    var txt = data["weather"][0]["description"];

    x = temp2 + "°C";
    temp1.innerHTML = x;

    if (info == "Clear") {
        image.src = "Icons/animated/SVG/day_clear.svg";
        k = 1;
    }
```

My code is working I just don't know how to filter min_temp from, let's say, tomorrow 3AM.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's what can do this

Wondering you are calculating from today's 3:00 PM or tomorrow's 3:00 PM or "next 3:00 PM", here I implement the "next 3:00 PM", have a response and I can Update this.

```js
fetch(
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Belgrade,rs&appid=b44c47165b17c02b98173f5270d92e80"
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    let startCount = false;
    let days = 0;

    const minimum = Math.min.apply(
      this,
      response.list
        .filter(function (data) {
          const hour = new Date(data.dt * 1000).getUTCHours();
          if (hour === 15 && !startCount) {
            startCount = true;
            return true;
          }

          if (hour === 0 && days < 3) {
            days += 1;
            return true;
          }

          if (startCount && days < 3) {
            return true;
          }

          return false;
        })
        .map((data) => data.main.temp_min)
    );

    return Promise.resolve(minimum);
  }).then(temp => console.log(temp))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I basically want to get today's min and max temperature, so as for next 3 days. It should look something like this. [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BIgICs8CYAAPrp5.png) I wanted to take 3AM temperature as Minimum and 3PM as maximum temperature for each day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, i think you should change the 3-days ago date depending on your needs.

```
            .then(data => {
            // date 3 days ago
            let date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 3);
            // Filter min temps of the last 3 days
            let minTemps = []
            data.list.forEach(entry => {
                if ( date<new Date(entry.dt_txt) ) {
                    minTemps.push(entry.main.temp_min)}
            });
            // Get the min temp
            let temp_min = Math.min(...minTemps)
            console.log("Min : ",temp_min)
        })
```